# Quit Browser-sync from terminal

Tags: browser-sync

How can you quit browser-sync from running in the terminal without quitting the terminal application itself?
I am new to using terminal-based frameworks and technologies so this is probably very basic, but I haven't found such command in the guides from their website. What I am trying to do is exiting browser-sync session and keep on using the terminal.

Comment: What website or guide are you following? Are you running browser-sync via Gulp, Grunt, or npm tasks? Create a task that doesn't run the browser-sync to skip over it.

Comment: I have no familiarity with gulp or grunt whatsoever. Just installed browser-sync via npm as shown in the guide from their website. I start the server using the commands provided in the same guide, but have no idea on how to quit it. Please consider I am truly a beginner using this kind of tools via the terminal - only used it for git so far... feel free to point me at any kind of resource that could enlighten me on what do here.... thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Just Press **`ctrl`** + **`c`** You will asked to press **`Y`** / **`N`** And if you press **`Y`** then the browser sync will stop along with other command line tools.

Answer (score 2):

I am also relatively new command-line and sorts, but I do believe that any local server can be terminated via "ctrl+c". While I am not sure about the general rule, I do know that ctrl+c works to exit browser sync in the terminal.

Comment: As stated by @ jojo in the other answer "ctr+c" is used to quit terminal processes in general. For instance you also use it to quit Gulp tasks.

Answer (score -2):

I assume you are using this guide to install browser-sync? https://www.browsersync.io/#install

People typically use browser-sync in conjunction with local client-server web development (like editing html and css, etc.), so you typically do not run browser-sync by itself.

Follow this video to get a better idea on how to integrate browser-sync into your workflow for web development: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heNWfzc7ufQ

That video shows how to start from a basic html file and use browser-sync to constantly watch for changes.

Comment: Thank you. I had already watched that tutorial to get started with browser-sync. It's very helpful and I am managing to watch my files while developing. But probably I have not made myself clear: what I don't understand is how do you exit the watching mode of browser sync and regain control of the terminal to perform other tasks, even for something as basic as changing directory - without having to quit the terminal and reopen it -. I can't find the proper command to pass to browser-sync in order to achieve this....

Comment: Press control and C.

Comment: thank you! sorry for the dumb question, but I still lack this kind of basic knowledge to operate the terminal.

Comment: Ctrl + C is a the standard *nix way of signaling a process to abort. It's not clear in the browser-sync documentation so don't blame yourself!